# Make developer story and the traditional view mobile-friendly

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, traditional-view

Let me tell you, people are using SO job profile as their professional CV, they link to it. And people are checking out CVs on their phones.

Recently, I've been through a job hunting session and I've been asked numerous times for a mobile-friendly CV instead of the link I provided to my SO traditional view.

I wonder, is there any chance that we see a mobile-friendly version of these pages in the near future?

Comment: Are you thinking something that looks like [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/4rpXP) (It's a mockup I just made showing how it would look on a Google Pixel)

Comment: Basically, yes. @jrtapsell

Comment: Personally, if a recruiter will check out my information on a phone, I wouldn't work for them.

Comment: @Teemu any reason for that opinion ?

Comment: @Webruster You can play with toys, but they are not purposed for a serious work.

Comment: @Teemu IMO having a candidate CV on phone instead of carrying a printed copy or a laptop is much more reasonable. This does not mean that the recruiter hasn't put the time to study your CV per se.

Comment: @sepehr I carry the link, and recruiters get familiar with the CV using proper hardware, (if I just had a one = )).

Comment: Google is moving to mobile first search though, so a mobile friendly page should theoretical rank higher